# How does Spring determine whether to redirect to form login?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

With a default Spring Boot app with Spring Security and Spring Mvc (straight out of Spring Initializr), the default settings are that if run the app and go to `localhost:8080` in the browser, it will redirect to `http://localhost:8080/login` using a `302` Found redirect.

However, if I run `curl -v localhost:8080` I instead see that I get a `401` Unauthorized response, challenging me with basic auth using a `WWW-Authenticate` header.

```bash
$ curl -v localhost:8080
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.86.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 401
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=2DB595DB974C991CAF036FD253C51C5B; Path=/; HttpOnly
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 0
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Mon, 20 Feb 2023 15:33:00 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

I'm wondering – how does Spring make this difference? It has to be some header that the browser is sending that triggers the redirect, but I have tried a number of the headers that my browser seems to send and no one triggered the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Duh, I figured this out while writing the question. It was simpler than I expected.

It's just that the browser is saying that it accepts `text/html` responses. This is a simple way of triggering it with `curl`:

```bash
$ curl -v localhost:8080 -H 'Accept: text/html'
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.86.0
> Accept: text/html
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 302
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=F180828EA95C98927FFC0FC02CBBA13F; Path=/; HttpOnly
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 0
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Location: http://localhost:8080/login
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Mon, 20 Feb 2023 15:37:53 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```